# Couchdb emit document from two arrays in document

Tags: javascript, couchdb, view

I have several documents in my couchdb database. Followng is an example of it:

```
    "company": [
           "xyz",
           "abcintl"
       ],
    "usermentions": [
           "Abce",
           "Swat",
           "axis"
       ],
```

I have a company name as my keyword. Let's say 'abcintl'. I want to emit a document who has 'abcintl' in company OR usermentions. 
If any of these attributes contain my keyword I want to emit that document.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the documents that contain a certain keyword, just emit the `company` and `usermentions` array values.

```
function (doc) {
  doc.company.forEach(function (company) {
    emit(company);
  });

  doc.usermentions.forEach(function (mention) {
    emit(mention);
  });
}
```

Your view will include all the company/usermentions for each document. So you can query your view with `key="abcintl"`, and you'll find all the document IDs that contain that value in either array.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But eventually I figured out that I did't need 'usermention'.